Creating Bar Charts based on query in Apache Suprset
Can we create charts based on the queries directly in Apache Superset?
When i am trying to create a bar chart based on a view, my view already has the aggregate column. So I dont want to pick an aggregate column in the metrics. How can I achieve that as it doesnt allow me to create a bar chart without selecting an aggregate function in the metrics
